# Complex hierarchical query in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical

Following is a data setup for which SQL needs to be written.

```
Table:parchil
par         chil
--------------------
E1          E2
E2          E3
E3          E4
E5          E6
E7          E8

Table:subval
sub         val
--------------------
E1          10
E2          70
E3          30
E4          40
E5          60
E6          20
E7          50

Expected result:
sub         val
--------------------
E1          150
E2          140
E3          70
E4          40
E5          80
E6          20
E7          50
```

I have the below query so far which is lengthy and far from elegant.

```
select a.par,sum(b.val) from
(select 'E1' as par,'E1' as chil from dual
union all
select
    'E1' as par, chil
from
   parchil
start with par='E1'
connect by prior chil=par
union all
select 'E2' as par,'E2' as chil from dual
union all
select
    'E2' as par, chil
from
   parchil
start with par='E2'
connect by prior chil=par
union all
select 'E3' as par,'E3' as chil from dual
union all
select
    'E3' as par, chil
from
   parchil
start with par='E3'
connect by prior chil=par
union all
select 'E4' as par,'E4' as chil from dual
union all
select
    'E4' as par, chil
from
   parchil
start with par='E4'
connect by prior chil=par
union all
select 'E5' as par,'E5' as chil from dual
union all
select
    'E5' as par, chil
from
   parchil
start with par='E5'
connect by prior chil=par
union all
select 'E6' as par,'E6' as chil from dual
union all
select
    'E6' as par, chil
from
   parchil
start with par='E6'
connect by prior chil=par
union all
select 'E7' as par,'E7' as chil from dual
union all
select
    'E7' as par, chil
from
   parchil
start with par='E7'
connect by prior chil=par
) a,
subval b
where
a.chil=b.sub
group by a.par
order by a.par;
```

Is there a way to solve this elegantly? Thanks.

Comment: why is E4 in the expected results but not E8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `cte` to do it;

```
WITH cte(sub,val,par,chil, lev) AS (
  SELECT s.sub, s.val, p.par, p.chil, 1 
  FROM subval s LEFT JOIN parchil p ON s.sub=p.par
  UNION ALL
  SELECT s.sub, s.val+c.val, p.par, p.chil, lev + 1
  FROM subval s LEFT JOIN parchil p ON s.sub=p.par
  JOIN cte c ON c.sub=p.chil
)
SELECT c1.sub,c1.val FROM cte c1 
LEFT JOIN cte c2
  ON c1.sub=c2.sub 
 AND c1.lev < c2.lev 
WHERE c2.sub IS NULL
ORDER BY sub;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc3be/1).

...or you can use a regular hierarchical query;

```
SELECT root, SUM(val) val
FROM 
( 
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT sub root, val 
  FROM subval s
  LEFT JOIN parchil p ON s.sub = p.par 
  CONNECT BY sub = PRIOR chil 
 )
GROUP BY root
ORDER BY root
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebdbd/1).

Answer (score 3):

you can use connect_by_root

```
select root, sum(val)
from 
 ( select chil, connect_by_root par root 
   from parchil 
   connect by par = prior chil 
   start with par in (select par from parchil )
   union all
   select par, par from parchil
 )
 , subval
 where 
   sub=chil
 group by root
 order by root
;
```